# Does Selenium Grid 4 for Firefox lack extension addon option?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, selenium-grid

I have Selenium working well locally, adding extensions with the following setup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as firefox_options

def init_firefox(self,threadname,headless,images_off):

        if headless == True:
            options=firefox_options()
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=(r"C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\python\gecko\geckodriver.exe"))
        else:
            options=firefox_options()
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=(r"C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\python\gecko\geckodriver.exe"))

        extension_dir = ('C:\\Users\\charl\\OneDrive\\python\\gecko\\extensions\\')
        extensions = [
            'firefox@vid.io.xpi',
            'noimages.xpi',
            ]
        
        for extension in extensions:
            driver.install_addon(extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
        self.close_tab(driver)        
        self.login(driver)
        return driver
```

But when I try the same on Selenium Grid 4 using this code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as firefox_options

def init_firefox_remote(self,threadname,headless,images_off):

        if headless == True:
            #options = Options()
            options=firefox_options()
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub', options=options)
        else:
            options=firefox_options()
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub', options=options)

        extension_dir = ('/dev/shm/extensons/')
        extensions = [
            'firefox@vid.io.xpi',
            'noimages.xpi',
            ]
        
        for extension in extensions:
            driver.install_addon(extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
        self.close_tab(driver)        
        self.login(driver)
        return driver
```

I get an error:-

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'install_addon'
```

The version of Selenium Grid I am using is created like this

```
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-firefox:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210321
```

Any ideas? Does Selenium Grid for Firefox lack the install extension option?

Answer (score 0):

Installing addons in a remote Firefox browser is done by creating a Firefox profile and adding the extension there:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = FirefoxOptions()

profile.add_extension("/path/to/extension.xpi")

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub",
                          options=options,
                          browser_profile=profile)
```

I don't think it is possible to load a temporary addon in a remote firefox browser.

Comment: browser_profile has been deprecated.
Here's a way to do it:

```
browser_options = FirefoxOptions()
browser_options.headless = True
str_ublock_extension_path = "/path/extension.xpi"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path/geckodriver',options=browser_options)
browser.install_addon(str_ublock_extension_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`install_addon` is only available for local webdrivers. A simple workaround is required when using remote webdrivers, as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-docs/issues/1621).

More specifically, change this line:

```py
driver.install_addon(extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
```

to

```py
webdriver.Firefox.install_addon(driver, extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
```

---

The full code should look like the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as firefox_options

def init_firefox_remote(self,threadname,headless,images_off):

        if headless == True:
            #options = Options()
            options=firefox_options()
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub', options=options)
        else:
            options=firefox_options()
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub', options=options)

        extension_dir = ('/dev/shm/extensons/')
        extensions = [
            'firefox@vid.io.xpi',
            'noimages.xpi',
            ]
        
        for extension in extensions:
            webdriver.Firefox.install_addon(driver, extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
        self.close_tab(driver)        
        self.login(driver)
        return driver
```

I have opened [a pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/pull/1267) to the Selenium Docs to clarify such usages.